# How to get data from websockets immedeatly after its change Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I have a websockets event from which I get data, but I need to update it immedeatly when data is arrived in websoket. I have read about stream, but it works only with `Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2))` and return Future which is static. I want to subscibe to update from future and receive data immediately after the update. Future doesn't allow me to do this and I have to reload the page before getting new data.

But when i use the `stream.periodic` my websocket image starts to flicker, but i don't need it. The image must be static and appear instantly.

What should I change to achive this goal? May be there is some way to combine ValuistanableBuilder and websockets?

My code:

```
List wanted = [];
static Stream<List?> getWanted() => Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10))
      .asyncMap((event) => fetchWantedFixation());

  static Future<List> fetchWantedFixation() async {
    final httpConnectionOptions = HttpConnectionOptions(
        accessTokenFactory: () => SharedPreferenceService().loginWithToken(),
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets);
    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'http://my securelink/',
          options: httpConnectionOptions,
        )
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    String? wantedFixation;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7))
        .then((value) => alarmplayer.StopAlarm());
    hubConnection.on('Wanted', (arguments) {
      HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
      // SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
      wanted = arguments as List;
      alarmplayer.Alarm(url: 'assets/wanted.mp3', volume: 0.25);
    });

    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
    print(wanted);
    return wanted;
  }
}
```

Comment: In the official documentation there a lot of differences with your code. Maybe there is something to do with that , try matching it to the documentation
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client, I have used this